# .Net MVC 4 using Windows Authentication - redirect unauthorized user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC 4 intranet app that I created using Visual Studio 2012. I used WindowsAuthentication and it authenticates users as expected. On some actions I restricted users to certain roles using `Authorize` attribute. When a user clicks on a link that invokes a controller action for which the user has no authorization it pops up an 'Authentication Required' dialogue. When I login with an account that has no authorization it keeps on popping up the dialogue. Instead I would like this:

1. When a user is not authorized to access the page, pop up the dialogue as currently doing.
2. When the user inputs a login that is valid but not authorized to access the page redirect to another page saying the access is forbidden.

How do I go about doing this? As a relevant information I customized the role provider using the approach discussed [here](https://codeutil.wordpress.com/2013/05/14/forms-authentication-in-asp-net-mvc-4/#mvc-implement-custom-role-provider)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you will need a Custom Authorization to handle the unauthorized situations yourself.

You will need a method like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class AuthorizeAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new System.Web.Mvc.HttpStatusCodeResult((int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this got me started in the right direction. Instead of standard error I am doing a redirect to a custom page that also provides a link to login as another user. I used the approach from the following link for doing that: http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/08/how-to-force-sign-in-as-different-user.html